# hide keyboard in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, ios6, ios7

In my App I am doing registartion through the Twitter. so user can register into my app through the twitter. I want to show Alertview if user has not set account in settings. so user can navigate to settings for add twitter account. also i do not want to show keyboard which appears with `SLComposeViewController`. for this I used below code

```
SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    tweetSheet.view.hidden=TRUE;

    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:NO completion:^{
        [tweetSheet.view endEditing:YES];

    }];
```

in ios6  above code hides the `SLComposeViewController` & keyboard & shows the alertView that user not has twitter account. & after clicking on settings button of alertView it navigates to settings in phone.

> BUT in iOS7 , above code shows the keyboard & does not navigate to
>   settings after clicking on settings button.

so my question is -Why this happening . it works in ios6 but not in ios7. diffrent behaviour in different version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I solved this problem. see below code

```
SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]

       [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:NO completion:^{
           [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }];
```

for showing alertView with settings option I presented tweetSheet, if user already not added any account then it shows alertView With settings option. because it is alertView it does not enter `completion` `(completion:^{ })`area until we press any button of alertView. once you pressed anyone button then it enters into `completion` area & it dismisses tweetSheet thats why it does not shows keyboard.

Comment: Not able to see the popup in latest iOS version 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can go to setting ->Facebook via pressing alert dialog button in your app if user is not logged in Facebook account below iOS 5.1. but i think this functionality has been removed by Apple in iOS 6 or more version.(same problem with me )